# Searching Youtube videos using youtube-dl

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, discord.py

I am trying to build a Discord Music Bot and I need to search the YouTube using keywords given by the user. Currently I know how to play from a url.

```
       loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
       data = await loop.run_in_executor( None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
       if "entries" in data:
            data = data["entries"][0]

        filename = data["url"] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Youtube_DL has a `extract_info` method that you can use. Instead of giving it a link, you just have to pass `ytsearch:args` like so:

```py
from requests import get
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}

def search(arg):
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        try:
            get(arg) 
        except:
            video = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)['entries'][0]
        else:
            video = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)

    return video
```

A few important things with this function:

- It works with both words and urls
- If you make a youtube search, the output will be a list a dictionnaries. In this case, it will return the first result
- It will return a dictionnary containing the following informations:

  ```py
  video_infos = search("30 sec video")

  #Doesn't contain all the data, some keys are not very important
  cleared_data = {
      'channel': video['uploader'],
      'channel_url': video['uploader_url'],
      'title': video['title'],
      'description': video['description'],
      'video_url': video['webpage_url'],
      'duration': video['duration'], #in seconds
      'upload_date': video['upload_data'], #YYYYDDMM
      'thumbnail': video['thumbnail'],
      'audio_source': video['formats'][0]['url'],
      'view_count': video['view_count'],
      'like_count': video['like_count'],
      'dislike_count': video['dislike_count'],
  }
  ```

Comment: Not working: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'youtube_dl'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure youtube-dl is good to search for youtube urls using keywords. You should probably take a look at [youtube-search](https://pypi.org/project/youtube-search/) for this.