# Searching for multiple Youtube videos using yt-dlp in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

I'm trying to make a Discord bot in Python that plays Youtube videos as audios in a voice channel. Right now, my bot uses a combination using `yt_dlp` and `youtube_search`. It firstly uses `youtube_search` to get the URL of the video searched by keyword. Then, `yt_dlp` gets the direct audio link given to `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio`. However, this takes multiple seconds and I feel like it could be made shorter.

I found this post : [Searching Youtube videos using youtube-dl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388364/searching-youtube-videos-using-youtube-dl) that suggests to use this :

```
from requests import get
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}

def search(arg):
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        try:
            get(arg) 
        except:
            video = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)['entries'][0]
        else:
            video = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)

    return video
```

This looks great to me, however I'm trying to get the top 5 results. I found the equivalent of that command from the same module, but on my terminal, which is, for the keyword hello

```
yt-dlp ytsearch5:hello --get-url --get-title --print uploader
```

Can anyone help me turning that into a Python command? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py), `extract_info` will:

> Return a list with a dictionary for each video extracted.

In your case, you need the top 5 from this list but in your code you only take the very first one with `[0]`. Change this to `[0:5]` to get the top 5.

```py
from requests import get
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist':'True'}

def search(arg):
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        try:
            get(arg) 
        except:
            video = ydl.extract_info(f"ytsearch:{arg}", download=False)['entries'][0:5]
        else:
            video = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)

    return video
```

Comment: Yep it's this, except i needed to transform `ytsearch:` into `ytsearch5:` so it'd look up 5 results