# Searching for Youtube videos with specific quality using yt-dlp in python

Tags: python, youtube-dl, yt-dlp

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73130689/searching-for-multiple-youtube-videos-using-yt-dlp-in-python), I try to use `yt-dlp` to search Youtube videos specifically in 720p or 1080p (preferably 1080p). The `ytsearchX` URL seems rather undocumented. I would like to know if it is possible to filter out poor quality videos.